# remove duplicate id from an array in for loop

Tags: php

i have different parameters...on the products...but i want to display only those parameters that are clicked by the user.i have done this but i want to delete the duplicacy.. my code is:-

```
$ab=$_POST['data1'];
$karan=explode(",",$ab);
array_pop($karan);

for($i=0;$i<count($karan);$i++){
    'karan['.$i.'] = '.$karan[$i];

    $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM demo_postmeta WHERE meta_value='".$karan[$i]."' ");

    $out=array();
    foreach($posts as $post){       


        if (!isset($out[$post->post_id])){

            $out[$post->post_id][$post->meta_key]=$out;



            $ram=get_the_post_thumbnail($post->post_id,"_thumbnail_id",true);
            $title=get_post_meta($post->post_id,"_product_title",true);
            $price=get_post_meta($post->post_id,"_product_year",true);
            $link=get_post_meta($post->post_id,"_product_likes",true);
?>      



<div id="itemListContent" class="in-list">
    <div class="the-list">
        <div class="li first row clearfix" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="c-1 table-cell">
                <div class="cropit">
                    <a class="pics-lnk important-rule" href="http://uzodocs.com/PROJECTS/demo/products?post_id=<?php echo $post->post_id ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <?php echo $ram; ?> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second-column-container  table-cell">
                <h3>
                    <a href="http://uzodocs.com/PROJECTS/demo/products?post_id=<?php echo $post->post_id ?>" title="Kenxinda Watch Mobile Dual SIM with FREE Bluetooth Headset free home delivery - Delhi" class="important-rule" style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <?php echo $title; ?>
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <div class="c-4">
                </div>
                <span class="itemlistinginfo clearfix">
                    <span>
                        Delhi | 
                        Cameras
                        - Camera Accessories
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="third-column-container table-cell">

                <?php echo $price; ?>

            </div>

            <div class="fourth-column-container table-cell"><br>  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="li even row clearfix" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <div class="c-1 table-cell">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php       

        }
        $out[$post->post_id][$post->meta_key][] = $post->post_id;


    }


}
die;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
This may be a way to solve your problem:

```
if (!in_array($post->post_id, $out)){

        $out[] = $post->post_id;
```

You can remove the last `$out[$post->post_id][$post->meta_key][] = $post->post_id;`

Comment: well which variable contains the duplicates?

Comment: if the product have multiple parameter then it show the product multiple times.

Comment: I'll contact you in like 4 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Just put you required data into 
    $out[$post->post_id][$post->meta_key][] = "data you need". 
and put this array out of for scope. just before die;